# (Python (analysis)) Unable to resolve 'pandas'. IntelliSense may be missing for this module

Tags: python, visual-studio, pandas, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am working on a python app in Visual Studio Code and would like to import `pandas`, `sqlalchemy`, and `flask` libraries.  However, when I enter code such as

```
    import pandas as pd
    import sqlalchemy
```

I get the error `[Python (analysis)] Unable to resolve 'pandas'. IntelliSense may be missing for this module`
Likewise with sqlalchemy.

I checked the version of pandas in the command line by

```
    pip3 install --upgrade pandas
```

and it returns "`Requirement already up-to-date`".

So I am not sure what the issue is.  Any suggestions? Many thanks.

Comment: you probably have multiple installations of `python`. The one that you installed `pandas` in is not the interpreter used in VS Code. Try [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments)

Comment: Thanks for the link Vivek, that helped.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Vivek Kalyanarangan for providing the link. It was a fairly simple (but hard to know in a first encounter) answer. In my case, there were several versions of `python` installed on my computer and the `pandas`, `flask`, and `sqlalchemy` libraries were in a different directory than the interpreter version. So I changed to the appropriate interpreter to navigate around the issue. Am also working on putting the libraries in the right place. Thanks.